# Disablecontrols dos not affect on review speed for FDTable or FDQuery with lookup field on Delphi Embarcadero 10.2 or 11

Tags: database, delphi

I have a **FDTable** with some lookup fields with thousands of records.
when I review **FDTable** with this code:

```
FDTable1.AutoCalcFields:=false;
FDTable1.DisableControls;
FDTable1.First;
while FDTable1.Eof<>true do
begin
  // some code....
  FDTable1.Next;
end;
FDTable1.EnableControls;
FDTable1.AutoCalcFields:=true;
```

It consume a lot of time.
When I remove lookup field from table , this cod run very fast.

it is necessary to mention that, this code run with **ADOTable** very fast for table that contain lookup fields.
How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the dataset's [`AutoCalcFields`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.AutoCalcFields) property to `False`.

> Determines when the [OnCalcFields](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields) event is triggered and when lookup
> field values are calculated.
>
> Set **AutoCalcFields** to control when the [OnCalcFields](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields) event is triggered
> to update calculated fields and when lookup fields are calculated.
>
> A calculated field is one that derives its value from the values of
> one or more fields in the active record, sometimes with additional
> processing. Lookup fields are fields whose values come from a
> secondary dataset or lookup cache.
>
> **Note:** Unidirectional datasets support calculated fields but not
> unidirectional fields. For unidirectional datasets, [OnCalcFields](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields) only
> controls when calculated fields are updated.
>
> When **AutoCalcFields** is **True** (the default), [Lookup](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Lookup) fields are
> recalculated and OnCalcFields is triggered when:
>
> - The dataset is opened.
> - The dataset is put into dsEdit state.
> - Focus moves from one visual control to another, or from one column to
>   another in a data-aware grid and modifications have been made to the
>   record.
>
> When **AutoCalcFields** is **False**, [Lookup](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Lookup) fields are recalculated
> and the [OnCalcFields](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields) event occurs only when:
>
> - The dataset is opened.
> - The dataset is put into dsEdit state.
> - A record is retrieved from a database.
>
> If an application permits users to
> change data, [OnCalcFields](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields) is frequently triggered. In these cases an
> application may set **AutoCalcFields** to **False** to reduce the frequency
> with which the [OnCalcFields](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields) event occurs and with which lookup values
> are fetched.

Also the field's [`LookupCache`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Data.DB.TField.LookupCache) property might help you.

Comment: @Febrizio : With adding of FDTable1.AutoCalcFields:=false; and LookupCache:=true; no  effect occur  on speed of review of table.

Comment: @A.K.D. : Try setting the `LookupCache` property to `True` for all your lookup fields

Comment: @Febrizio : With LookupCache=true  for FDQuery, review of table fast by 8 times and it is acceptable, but for FDTable review fast by 2 times and it has little effect.
It is necessary to mention that, review of ADOTable with same structure table that contain lookup fields is very fast .